# Flex SWF Accepting Play or Rewind Command from the Flash Player (Projector)

Tags: flash, apache-flex

I'm trying to make my Flex SWF act like a Flash movie SWF so that when the user issues the Play command in the FLash Player it can trigger an event in my Flex SWF file. I'm not sure what event this would hook into or if this is possible with Flex. Any help appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: What is the play command in the Flash Player?  I loaded up a Flex app and 'play' was not an option in the context menu.

Comment: Yeah, that the issue I'm trying to get at. If you load a movie instead, you will see the option.

Comment: Every Flex movie has two frames; what are you expecting 'play' to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to use the 'play' in Flex per say since even though Flash is a frame based VM, Flex is masked against that so that users can use frame based actions.

What would be the requirement to have Flex have a 'play/rewind' command?  What would it rewind if there's no frame?

Comment: I have a requirement to when the 'play' command on the player, it would fire an event to do some work and then wither play a movie or load an image. In a sense, it's suppose to act like a movie but it needs to do work when the 'play/stop' gets invoked.

Comment: so, it's not on the Flash Player, but on a movie player within it? Your question is lacking a lot of information then.

Comment: For my requirements, I can either load a movie or an image file into the application. So I have a SWFLoader in the application to handle the that, but I noticed that playing a movie in the flex application as opposed to playing a straight movie in the flash player is different. When playing the movie, I can pause and play the movie without doing anything special other than encoding the movie file. For my flex application, I like to be able to fire an event on those same 'play' command that starts the movie. I hope that I enough info, let know if you need more.

Comment: A flv, swf, or image that can be loaded by the SWFLoader.

Comment: SWFLoader isn't a 'player', it just loads the content.  You need to create code to see what type of content you're loading and do what you need to do with it (like add it to a video display).  From there, just have a 'play' function for that class.