# Is Flex SWC compiled differently from movie in SWC

Tags: flash, apache-flex, flex3

Are Flex swc file encoded differently from say movies file encode in SWC?

Comment: Encoded differently in what way? What information are you looking for specifically?

Comment: Yes, I'm thinking about how flash movie have the play and stop options when you right-click on it when playing in the flash player, and those options are not available on the flex file. I was wondering if there is a difference on how the file is built. If so, is there a way to enable the play and stop option on the flex swc, so I can hook events on them.

Comment: I believe that depends on how the **.swf** is compiled and not the **.swc**. Are the movies also being compiled from FlashBuilder?

Comment: I updated my answer after looking at your other question. Hopefully it helps solve your issue. If it does help solve your issue, you can mark it as the accepted answer by clicking on the check mark icon next to my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE:**

Assuming this question is related to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6091338/flex-swf-accepting-play-or-rewind-command-from-the-flash-player-projector), what you should look into is using the [ContextMenu](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/ui/ContextMenu.html) and adding the Play and Stop commands yourself. This way you can wire them up to play a movie or load an image or whatever it is you need to do.

Here's [another link](http://blog.flexexamples.com/2008/11/07/adding-custom-context-menu-items-to-a-flex-application/) to get you started.

Based on [this writeup from Adobe](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=building_overview_5.html), I'm going to guess that they're going to be roughly the same since a .swc file is basically a .swf file and a catalog.xml file.

> A SWC file is an archive file for Flex
>   components and other assets. SWC files
>   contain a SWF file and a catalog.xml
>   file. The SWF file inside the SWC file
>   implements the compiled component or
>   group of components and includes
>   embedded resources as symbols. Flex
>   applications extract the SWF file from
>   a SWC file, and use the SWF file's
>   contents when the application refers
>   to resources in that SWC file. The
>   catalog.xml file lists of the contents
>   of the component package and its
>   individual components.

Comment: Hey Jason, thanks! Another question, is there a way for the Play option on the Flash Player menu Context/Play to hook into my SWC? I was under the assumption that the context menu and the Context menu on the Flash Player are the same.

Comment: @Wit In a sense they are the same. The biggest difference is that Flex apps aren't compiled with a timeline, so they don't have the play and stop context menu commands a swf movie might. What Flex allows you to do is add your own options and commands to the context menu. While you can't hook into the play and stop commands a timeline based swf would have, you can create your own play and stop context menu options and have them do whatever you need.